# Programatically (C#) update QC/ALM Test Plan > Test Script tab content

Tags: c#, alm, test-plan

I am trying to programmatically (C#) overwrite the default generated contents of the Test Script tab for a QC/ALM VAPI-XP-TEST Test Plan.

I have been able to create/update the content of the Details, Design Steps, Parameters, etc tabs using code from the web, but cannot find refs on how to do the Test Script tab.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**SOLUTION:**

1. run the first 6 lines of code in step 5 to create a VAPI-XP-TEST.
2. In the created test > Test Script tab, go to the referenced Script path in Windows Explorer. Looks something like this:

   `C:\Users\user_id\AppData\Local\Temp\TD_80\ip_address\hex_code\Test`
3. open any child node folder path all the way until you see a test.sr file
4. Copy the test.sr file to the same folder as your VB Script file
5. change C# code as follows:

   ```
        TestFactory TF = qc.TestFactory; // qc is the ALM connection
        Test test = (Test)TF.AddItem(System.DBNull.Value);
        test["TS_NAME"] = "test name";
        test["TS_TYPE"] = "VAPI-XP-TEST";
        test["TS_SUBJECT"] = "Test Plan folder path/node id";
        test.Post();
        // add your script.vbs to Test Script tab of Test Plan test. 
        var es = test.ExtendedStorage; 
        es.ClientPath = "folder of your script.vbs and copied test.sr file"; 
        es.Save("script.vbs, test.sr", true);
   ```
6. re-run your C# code and check Test Script tab of Test Plan test to see your VB script.